# React Typescript Functional Component Syntax Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-functional-component

I want to create a generic functional component but i get this [image: Error] :

Code block ;

```
interface IAppTable<Type> {
  height: number;
  data: Type[];
  tableLayout: 'auto' | 'fixed';
  pagination?: false;
}

const AppTable: <T>(props: IAppTable<T>) => React.FC<IAppTable<T>> = (props) => {
  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState<number[]>([]);
  const getColumns = () => {
    setSelectedRows([1]);
    return [];
  };
  return <></>;
}
```

Comment: `AppTable` doesnot return React.FC , it is React.FC

Should be like :  AppTable: React.FC<IAppTable<T>>

Comment: @ShreyGupta so how can i create Generic Functional Component?

Comment: Is [that](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-grass-ijs41?file=/src/App.tsx) what you mean? Take under consideration that `AppTable` doesn't know the `data` type so you can't access to its properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by @Shrey, `AppTable` doesn't *return* a function component, it *is* a function component.

The `React.FC` type does not support generic components.  This isn't a problem because anything that matches the signature of `FC` can be used as an `FC`.  That signature is that it takes an object of props and returns a `JSX.Element`.  `FC` automatically includes the `children` prop, but we can use the helper `React.PropsWithChildren` to add it ourselves.

We need to make the function itself generic, so we apply the types to the props and the return rather than to the function itself (which is what `React.FC` does, and why it cannot work with a generic).

```
import React, { useState, PropsWithChildren } from "react";

const AppTable = <T extends any>(props: PropsWithChildren<IAppTable<T>>): JSX.Element => {
  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState<number[]>([]);
  const getColumns = () => {
    setSelectedRows([1]);
    return [];
  };
  return <></>;
}
```